# typcast does not cast the whole string to int (in C)

Tags: c, casting

I have a problem. Typecast works not like I want. So I have a variable called `sz` of type char array. This array contains `0x421`. But I want this as an integrer, not as a string. So I tried typecasting like that:

```
char sz[16];
strcpy(sz, "\x21\x04");
printf("%d\n", (int)*sz);
```

But this does only output `33` which is `0x21`. But where is the `0x4` in front? My ltrace output:

```
strcpy(0x7ffdc6cf4b70, "!\004")                                                    = 0x7ffdc6cf4b70
printf("%d\n", 33)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `*sz` is only ever going to be a single character. That is, you are casting a `char` to `int` and not a string to `int`. And casting a string to an int would not do what you want anyway.

Comment: `(int)*sz` -> `*(int*)sz`. But it is a dangerous game.

Comment: @IrAM atoi does not work, because it does convert only numbers as a string like 1 (`0x31`) to int, but not unprintable characters

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you. It works now

Comment: Be aware that the `*(int*)sz` cast is dangerous. It's going to read sizeof(int) bytes from the buffer. This will typically be 4 or 8 bytes, but your buffer has only 3 initialized bytes in it. It also risks a bus error on alignment-sensitive systems. And of course it is a potential aliasing violation which could take you into UB in which case the compiler is free to behave any way it likes (including reformatting your hard drive).

Comment: @RaymondChen I forgot to include, that I used `char sz[16] = {0};`, to set all elements to zero. Also the buffer is not user-controllable, so I think I'm save

Comment: You can use something like `(unsigned char)sz[0] | ((unsigned char)sz[1] << 8)`.

Comment: If you *really* must do something like this, I would go with `int x; memcpy(&x, sz, sizeof x);` - this will remove the potential UBs. Well, except for trap representation.

Comment: You probably need to add `alignas(int)` to the declaration of `sz` to avoid the bus error. I heartily endorse @IanAbbott's recommendation to combine the values manually. This avoids being endian-dependent. It's also [what Rob Pike recommends](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html). Modern compilers [optimize this handily](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qcdvqP).

Comment: @RaymondChen Even `alignas()` won't address the strict aliasing violation and the resulting UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*sz` is the same as `sz[0]`, i.e. the first character of the string. In your case the first character has the numeric value 33 (aka hex 0x21). In other words, your code prints 33.

If you want to convert the first `sizeof(int)` characters to an integer, you should use bit shifting instead.

If `sizeof(int)` is 4 and you want little endian conversion, it would be something like:

```
int n = (sz[3] << 24) + (sz[2] << 16) + (sz[1] << 8) + sz[0];
```

note: depending on whether char is signed or unsigned, you may have to add a cast to unsigned before shifting.

note: Instead of `+` you can also use `|` (i.e. bitwise OR).

Comment: `sz[3] << 24` causes undefined behaviour for some inputs (as does `sz[1] << 8` if it's a 16-bit system). Emphasis needs to be placed on the "something like"... it would improve the answer to use a correct version of the code